# SQL special select from table

Tags: sql

I have a table with about 20 columns and 2000 rows.
Example:

```
Col1   Col2  Col3  Col4   ...
A01    22     AB   11
A01    22     AX   112
A01    23     A5   11
A02    20     AB   AA
A04    21     AB   11
A04    21     AU   11
A04    29     AB   BA
A05    21     AB   11
AAA    111    XX   18
AAA    222    GT   1O 
...
```

I need a select which displays all rows and all columns that satisfy the requirement of two columns (Col1 and Col2) based on the following:

if Col1 is unique - show row,
or
if Col1 is not unique show all row only if Col1 and Col2 are same.
From the previos table is after select the result:

```
Col1   Col2  Col3  Col4   ...
A01    22     AB   11
A01    22     AX   112
A02    20     AB   AA
A04    21     AB   11
A04    21     AU   11
A05    21     AB   11
AAA    111    XX   18
...
```

The new table (your solution) contains data:
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 ...

A01   22   AB   11

A01   22   AX   112

A02   20   AB   AA

A04   21   AB   11

A04   21   AU   11

A05   21   AB   11

AAA  111   XX   18

...

what I wont see from this is:

Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 ...

A01    2   AB   11

A02    1   AB   AA

A04    2   AB   11

A05    1   AB   11

AAA    1   XX   18

...

Comment: Finally, wich RDBMS are you using? You have one correct answer that works for Oracle but seems that you need a MS SQL Server answer

Comment: @Yaroslav: My answer works for both Oracle and MS SQL :-)

Comment: @Peter: You really should try my answer - it works, I promise ;-)

Comment: Yes, I realized that after testing

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle and MS SQL I would use analytical functions:

```
select * from
(
    select
        t.* ,
        count(Col1) over (partition by Col1) as count_col1,
        count(Col2) over (partition by Col1, Col2) as count_col2
    from yourTable t
) t
where count_col1 = 1 or count_col2 > 1;
```

See [this fiddle (Oracle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5502b/1) and [this fiddle (MSSQL)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/233d7/11) as proof.

Comment: Thank very much Daniel, but one problem remained. If in table are two rows with

Comment: Sory it was wrong answer,so again. Thank very much Daniel, but one problem remained. If in table are two rows with line x col1=AAA, col2=111 and line y col1=AAA and col2=222 in select I do not see no one line. Line x or y is for me important to see.

Comment: @Peter: That is something else completely... What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Thank Daniel for help.It is a special table, what I received, and I have a task to create reports from data with more view. Best regards, Peter

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from table t1
join (select col1
      from table
      group by col1
      having avg(col2)=max(col2)) t2
     on t1.col1=t2.col1
```

Seeing that I didn't look at your example .. and your request is slightly different then the example, Because my query checks that for a col1 all col2 should be the same. It will not display the ones that are the same.

In this case the answer will be

```
select * 
from table1 t1
join (select col1,col2
      from table1
      group by col1,col2
      having count(*)>1
      union
      select col1,cast(null as varchar)
      from table1 group by col1
      having count(*)=1) t2
     on t1.col1=t2.col1 and t1.col2=isnull(t2.col2,t1.col2)
```

This is the updated query, and the fiddle for it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e944b/2/0

Ok .. updated one more time:

```
select * 
from table1 t1
join (select col1,col2
     from table1
     group by col1,col2
     having count(*)>1
     union
     select col1,min(col2)
     from table1 group by col1
     having count(*)=1 or count(*)=count(distinct col2)) t2
     on t1.col1=t2.col1 and t1.col2=t2.col2
```

and with fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5437/12/0

This should be enough for the second problem:

```
select t3.* 
    from (select distinct col1 from table1)t1
    cross apply (select top 1 * from table1 t2 where t1.col1=t2.col1) t3
```

and the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e944b/4/0

Comment: -1: Returns incorrect result. It doesn't return `A01 | 22` or `A04 | 21`

Comment: I didn't tested, but I doubt that it does not return correct.

Comment: Well, I **did** test it and it only returns those rows where there is only one Col2 per Col1. Take A01 for example. There are two rows with 22 and one row with 23. The average of this is 22.333 but the max is 23, so in your code no row for A01 is returned, although it should return the two rows with Col2 = 22.

Comment: can you please clarify "average" because average is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Peter: In Oracle it is `AVG`.

Comment: I just tested in sql 2008 and it works fine .. still use AVG Peter

Comment: I wrote the correct average function .. I usually do not stay to test the sql .. and I might miss some complete function names .. but the functionality will work.

Comment: Thanks, avg is correct. But I think, that I can not use this function, because the Col2 is a varchar type and I receive Error message " Operand type varchar is invalid for avg operator"

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan: It doesn't work. [Proof](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/233d7/2)

Comment: If your Col2 is varchar then this solution does not work. Nevertheless, @DumitrescuBogdan, here is the [SQL Fiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64237/4) and it does not work, only returns A02 and A05 rows.

Comment: I wrote a correction .. cause the request is slightly different then the example, and I just didn't look at the example ..

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan, there are no A02 and A05 values on your result set with the new change and they should appear. Also remember Col2 is VARCHAR. See [Fiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e944b/1)

Comment: It does not matter that col2 is varchar. Anyway .. my bad for not looking at the example ..

Comment: Thank Bogdan its work, but A02 and A05 that are uniquie, they are not in result

Comment: Yes I know, I understood anyway the problem wrong. Daniel's query is correct for your given problem. The easiest way to solve it. My second query misses another group by only on the first column, if you want to make that work.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth already answered for both RDBMS. I know varchar type was not the issue, but when answering, I always try to follow all question details if possible. A small change can (not on this case) result on an incorrect or unusefull answer.

Comment: Sorry Bogdan,I really appreciate your help, I do not know to solve this problem.

Comment: @Peter: Simply use [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12085875/572644). It solves your problem.

Comment: Daniel's answer is good for your problem. I will also make my second answer to do correct, but Daniel's is good.

Comment: Unmarked the -1 as @DumitrescuBogdan edited the answer and now is correct

Comment: Thank very much Bogdan, but in Daniel solution one problem remained. If in table are two rows with line x col1=AAA, col2=111 and line y col1=AAA and col2=222 in select I do not see no one line. Line x or y is for me important to see.

Comment: Thank Bogdan. Your solution has the same problem like Daniels solution

Comment: It can be anyone of the 2 ? For example the first one ? AAA / 111 ?

Comment: Bogdan thank you very much. Your solution is perfect. Best regards, Peter. If you have a time for me, I would like to ask you to help me on completion this task. I save this new table for further use (its for me very important). This new table (your solution)  I wont a modify for show only one row with the same col1 and to col2 I wont write sum of rate col1. Thank, Peter

Comment: Yes. The new table contains data 
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 ... 
A01 22 AB 11 
A01 22 AX 112 
A02 20 AB AA 
A04 21 AB 11 
A04 21 AU 11 
A05 21 AB 11 
AAA 111 XX 18
... 
what I wont see from this is: 
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 ... 
A01 2 AB 11 
A02 1 AB AA 
A04 2 AB 11 
A05 1 AB 11 
AAA 1 XX 18 
...

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan: Changed -1 to +1 because of your persistence :-)

Comment: Thank Bogdan, but I receive a error message: Column names in each table must be unique. Column name "Col1" in table "Table1" is specified more then once". Can you me write where I make mistake?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth if I can help and if I have the time, I do it gladly.

Peter in what context you have that error ? You might try to create a table or a temp table specifying the same name twice. (or you just select * from a join and try to create a table out of it)

Comment: I made a mistake, sorry. All is well and very, very thank for help. Best regards, Peter